# I can't get my images with MYSQLi

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I'm struggling to transfer my files to MYSQLi. I've managed to get my data into a table adapting code from an online tutorial but I can't find anything that tells me how to get the image into the table. I've tried all sorts of wrong ways which obviously didn't work. This is the latest. Can anyone put me on the right track? It works fine without the images. The field is called Images. Could that be a problem?

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','data_base');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM engravers");

print '<table border="1" >';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
print '<tr>';
print '<td>'.$row["Key"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Year"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Engraver1Surname"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Designer1Surname"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Printer"].'</td>';

   $img_url = "http://www.xxxx.net/images/"; 
   { 
    print  '<td>'<img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" />'</td>'; 

print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';


$results->free();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You have unmached `'`. Try `print  '<td><img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" /></td>';`

Comment: its better to put your $img_url before the while loop and also what is the { you opened after $img_url.

Comment: This forum is the best. I've been playing with this for hours without finding those things. After three months it feels like I'm finally getting somewhere. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to put img tag in ''.
so just try this:

```
  print  '<td>'.'<img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" />'.'</td>';
```

also its better to put $img_url before the while loop:

```
  $img_url = "http://www.xxxx.net/images/"; // put this before while 
  print '<table border="1" >';
  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
  print '<tr>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Key"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Year"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Engraver1Surname"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Designer1Surname"].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$row["Printer"].'</td>';
  print  '<td>'.'<img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" />'.'</td>'; // put the img tag in ''
  print '</tr>';
  }  
  print '</table>';
```